# Utilizando valor pré-definido no HTML5

Tags: html, formulário, input

Estou tentando trazer um valor para um input text disabled mas o campo está sendo mostrado como vazio. Já removi o disabled e ele continua vindo em branco.

```
<input type="text" name="anterior" id="anterior" size="13" maxlength="50" disabled="disabled" value"123456,78" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 - O atributo `disabled` é um atributo para indicar o que o próprio nome diz `'desabilitato'`, ou seja, ele não será hábil dentro de formulário.

2 - Mesmo com o atributo `disabled`, o valor aparece, no seu caso não está aparecendo pois a propriedade `'value'` está sem o `'='`, basta corrigir para:

```
value="123456,78"
```

3 - Para possuir um input não editável que seja contabilizado pelo form, utilize do atributo `'readonly'`, que também significa o próprio nome 'apenas leitura', com esse atributo o valor do campo não é editavel, mas é hábil dentro do formulário.

Seu input correto (Caso queira submeter o dado via formulário) deveria ser:

```html
<input type="text" name="anterior" id="anterior" size="13" maxlength="50"  value="123456,78" readonly />
```

E outra opção (caso não queira que o dado seja submetido via form) deveria ser:

```html
<input type="text" name="anterior" id="anterior" size="13" maxlength="50"  value="123456,78" disabled='disabled' />
```

Answer (score 4):

Faltou o "=" depois do value.

Tente assim:

```
<input type="text" name="anterior" id="anterior" size="13" maxlength="50" disabled="disabled" value="123456,78" />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Importante**
O *disabled* é um elemento desativado, não é editável e não é enviado no envio de formulários. 
O melhor seria usar o *readonly* que é um elemento de leitura apenas não é editável, mas é enviado quando o formulário de acordo. E o readonly você pode focar etc, e o disabled não.

Exemplo de readonly: `<input readonly type="text" name="anterior" id="anterior" size="13" maxlength="50" value="123456,78" />`

Comment: Reveja seu exemplo, parece contrastar com sua explicação

Comment: Deixei meu -1 pois, ao meu ver, o problema não é relacionado ao fato de o campo ser *disabled*, como colocou na resposta. Nela dá a entender que um campo *disabled* não pode receber valor e isso não faz sentido. O único problema no código da pergunta é a ausência do igual no atributo `value`.

Comment: Sim, só comentei para conhecimento.

Answer (score 2):

Faltou o sinal de igual no value. Mude de `value"123456,78"` para `value="123456,78"`.